# Windows server 2012 hands out DHCP addresses without DHCP server - cannot disable

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server on my network which seems to be handing out DHCP addresses.
The addresses it hands out are on a subnet which does not exist on our network (ex: 192.168.30.0).

Other computers receive the new subnet via DHCP (192.168.30.0) even though:

- DHCP is DISABLED on our network and on the computers themselves
- The 2012 server is NOT configured as a DHCP server.

I cannot figure out what is causing this or how to disable it.

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you come to the conclusion it’s the Windows server? Have you checked for DHCP server processes and/or UDP listeners?

Comment: On the computers that receive the new subnet, I can see the gateway is `192.168.30.1`. The Windows server has that interface and MAC. I checked the server for DHCP listeners as well - nothing is running.

Comment: I would record network traffic (-> Wireshark) while a client performs a DHCP request (record the traffic on the client that performs the request). Then you will see which computer is really answering the DHCP request.

Comment: Thanks, double checked with wireshark - that is without a doubt the server spreading DHCP.

Comment: Sounds strange. Run `services.msc` on the server and look for "DHCP Server". If it exists, then the DHCP Server role is still enabled. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc thanks for responding. No DHCP server service on the machine - only a DHCP client. Tried disabling that as well (the server has a static IP) - the error remains.

Comment: Can the DHCP server be on another device, just sending the wrong gateway?

Comment: Do you have DHCP Reservations set in the Server?

Comment: Thank you both for the responses - there is a different DHCP server, but it is sending the correct gateway to clients - we managed to confirm by shutting down the 2012 server and issue really did go away. There are no DHCP reservations set in the server either - the server is entirely unrelated to anything DHCP.

Comment: As a workaround, you could block DHCP from the server via a firewall. I had a similar issue once with a client, the network cards got DHCP settings despite not having any DHCP server (not sure if it affected the rest of the network since it was a test environment), it helped to reset all network adapters including/especially the virtual ones on that client.